# Java MVC & Composite Design Pattern With Internal Frames

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jframe, composite, jinternalframe

Still wondering the best way to do Model-View-Controller Software Architecture, Do I pass the Controller into the View, or do I use the Observer Design Pattern and let the Controller Observe any changes/requests made by the view so we can update the model and redisplay that.......

I have A Main JFrame which will have JInternalframes, and i want to apply the MVC Architecture. Using just a normal Java Application

Kind of stuck on this any suggestions to limitations ect will help a lot.

Sorry For the confusion, didn't there was an web aspect that just uses Frame and Internal Frame

Comment: I suppose using observer will decouple the classes a bit so more expandability and less reliability

Comment: You should definitely separate model/view, but separating view/controller can be tricky.   You can read [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/#roots) that even Swing itself is not really MVC.

Comment: Thanx For that will have a read, looks good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a program with the MVC pattern last year but I can't seem to find the code atm, I DO recall that I used it with the observer pattern, so that the Controller listened to the View (so controller implements Observer, view implements Observable)

(note: I'm still a student so there may be some errors in my comments.. just trying to help though!)

Comment: Algood that is pretty much how i have it and what my understanding is of it haha. Thanx for your input :) Someone in my degree also one of my mates suggested using the Observer Pattern + MVC as you Decouple your code a bit making classes less dependant on each other and more flexible

Answer (score 1):

Your Mainframe contains all the frames, therefore they are accessible to it.
The internal frames should get their "father" frame in the constructor as a a parameter, and store it as a context variable.

That way you can use both: if you decide to pass controller (MainFrame), views (InternalFrames) can register on its event, or you can update view through your controller.

regarding your question , you should use the *Observer Design Pattern*.
this is logically correct to let the Controller control the flow and update the view upon model change.